# Separate objects in array by paired values in Angular / Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json

I currently have a large array with 120 objects.  Each one has an id value, and an opposite_id value, to basically pair two objects.  What is the best way to loop through each of the objects, and either put each pair in a new array or display the two as a pair?

As an example:

```
    Obj1 = {
        id: 1,
        opposite_id: 2,
        descr: "This is the first object"
   },
   Obj2 = {
        id: 2,
        opposite_id: 1,
        descr: "This is the second object"
   },
    Obj3 = {
        id: 3,
        opposite_id: 6,
        descr: "This is the third object"
   }
```

I would need to ultimately display Obj1 and Obj2 together (ideally with ng-repeat) as a pair while avoiding displaying Obj2 and Obj1 (since it'd be a repeat)...I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to do this particular action, any help would be much appreciated! Thank you

Comment: What's with `Obj1`, `Obj2`, etc? Are they literal variables? I thought this was meant to be in an array. Do the array indexes correspond at all to the object `id` properties?

Comment: This looks incredibly contrived.  Why don't you post your real code and data structure that demonstrates a real problem and we'll be able to help you much better.

Comment: Fixed, thank you! And Phil, no the index does not correspond to the object user.id property as the opponent gets randomized each week basically.

Comment: That object is incorrect, did you just write it out and not check it?
https://jsbin.com/mewovo/edit?js,console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way you could pair them.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("controller", function($scope) {
  var users = [{
    "id": 11,
    "user": {
      "id": 5,
      "first_name": "",
      "last_name": ""
    },
    "opponent": 2
  }, {
    "id": 12,
    "user": {
      "id": 6,
      "first_name": "",
      "last_name": ""
    },
    "opponent": 3
  }, {
    "id": 13,
    "user": {
      "id": 2,
      "first_name": "",
      "last_name": ""
    },
    "opponent": 5
  }, {
    "id": 14,
    "user": {
      "id": 3,
      "first_name": "",
      "last_name": ""
    },
    "opponent": 6
  }];

  $scope.pairs = [];
  var alreadyPaired = []; // ids of users that have already been paired

  for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    var user = users[i];
    
    // if this user hasn't already been paired
    if (alreadyPaired.indexOf(user.user.id) === -1) {
      var opponent = null;

      for (var j = 0; j < users.length; j++) {
        if (users[j].user.id === user.opponent) {
          opponent = users[j];
        }
      }

      $scope.pairs.push({
        user1: user,
        user2: opponent
      });

      alreadyPaired.push(user.user.id);
      alreadyPaired.push(opponent.user.id);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
  <h3>Pairs</h3>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>User</th>
        <th>Opponent</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="pair in pairs">
        <td>{{pair.user1.user.id}}</td>
        <td>{{pair.user2.user.id}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```